# Getting comp-id from div class in grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, ag-grid

Given an AG-Grid, I need to be able to get the `comp-id` number from the currently focused cell when pressing the tab key. I currently have an event listener on the div class, but it gives an error that `cell.addEventListener is not a function`

I'm trying to get the `comp-id` with the following:

```
const cell = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-cell');
cell.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.key === "Tab") {
      console.log("ID", comp-id);
    }
});
```

Link to Plunkr: [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/kgB1EkL6BWolKbsjVhJj?p=preview)

**UPDATE:**

I'm able to get the `comp-id` value by grabbing the attribute from the div:

```
if(e.key === "Tab"){
  let lastCell = cell.attributes[2].value;
}
```

although I noticed that it doesn't seem get the value after the 176th cell, even though there are more in the data grid.

Answer (score 0):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a sequence of type [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Meaning, it returns more than one cell.
So you need to add an event listener for each item (even though there is only 1 item in the collection).

⚠️ *Be aware that `map` is a method that belongs to an Array, so you need to turn an instance of HTMLCollection into an Array first (using either spread syntax or `Array.from`)*

```js
const cells = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-cell');
[...cells].map(cell => (
  cell.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      if (e.key === "Tab") {
        console.log("ID", comp-id);
      }
  })
)
```

Comment: I updated the plnkr with your answer, but it's not triggering the `comp-id` number on tab: https://plnkr.co/edit/kgB1EkL6BWolKbsjVhJj?p=preview

Comment: Would you provide code sample on the element, on which `ag-cell` class is applied on? That way we can figure out how to retieve `comp-id`.

Comment: The first cell in the data table is a good example: 
`<div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="19" col-id="athlete" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus" style="width: 200px; left: 0px;  ">Michael Phelps</div>`

Comment: I've updated my question with code that works, but introduces a new issue. It is unable to get the value of the data cell after a certain number. Any ideas?

Comment: I've never used `ag-grid` but it seems to have inifite-scrolling feature.  If that feature is turned on, https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#turning-on-infinite-scrolling the grid might not have rendered all records thus won't be able to retrieve data.